# Paillier encryption problem when q or p divides r

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, paillier

I am having a problem with Paillier encryption as described [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem).    It says to pick $0 < r < n$, where $n=pq$ for large, equally sized primes $p$ and $q$.  However, I've been testing this under trivial key sizes, setting p=11, q=13, and encrypting m=1.  When I try all legal values of r, I find that decryptions fail when $p | r$ or $q | r$.

(To be clear, I'm doing the gcd checks and seeking a random generator less than $n^2$, not using the "simpler variant" on the Wiki page although I have tried that, too, without success.)

I've seen a particular [Paillier implementation in Python](https://github.com/mikeivanov/paillier) in which the random value of $r$ is chosen to be a prime number, maybe to avoid this problem (I asked about it [in this thread](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/61288/49011)), but I see no such specification of a restriction on this randomness constant in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem) page or the original [Paillier paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-48910-X_16.pdf).

What am I doing wrong?  If it's appropriate to post ~40 lines of Python code on this forum, I will - please indicate in a comment.  I don't want to junk up the feed.

If this is a theoretic problem, what is a good limit to avoid choosing an r that is a multiple of p or q, without revealing knowledge of p or q to the party doing the encryption, (gcd with n is 1,) or is it just based on the law of large numbers that the sender will never land on such an r in practice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Paillier encryption, the ciphertext is $c=g^n \cdot r^n \bmod n^2$, and to decrypt, you compute $m=L(c^\lambda \bmod n^2)\cdot \mu \bmod  n$.

For decryption to be correct, $r$ must be a member of group $\Bbb Z_{n^2}^*$, so that $r^{n\lambda} \equiv 1 \bmod n^2$ and $r$ can be cancelled in the decryption process. If $p$ or $q$ divides $r$, then $r$ is not in $\Bbb Z_{n^2}^*$ thus cannot be cancelled and your decryption will be incorrect.

When you use small $p,q$, it is likely you can easily choose $r$ that is not in $\Bbb Z_{n^2}^*$. However, when $p,q$ are large, the probability that a random $0<r<n$ is not in $\Bbb Z_{n^2}^*$ is negligible (otherwise the RSA problem can be solved). So we usually can just use $0<r<n$, without any more constraints (requiring $r$ to be a prime to me is not necessary).

Comment: Thanks!  Is a simple sender test to ensure the gcd with n is one? Is it worth updating the Wiki page?

Comment: You can do that. But as I said, it is not necessary because the probility you pick an invalid $r$ is so small. Basically when you find an $r$ such that $gcd(r,n) \ne 1$, you obtain a factor of n, which means you can solve the RSA problem. The probability must be negligible.